# Trying to replace multiple strings in Notepad++ from a file

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, csv, find-and-replace, replacement

What I am doing is looking at multiple large text files, in these text files are common strings that need to be replaced. If it was a handful of instances I could use the Replace function, but I have 1220 cases where a string needs to be replaced. Is there a good way to use a csv file with these changes and apply it to multiple files. I have tried to use the 'Regular expression' feature in replace with no success:

ex.
(DoorOpen)|(DoorClosed)|(DoorMissing)...
(?door_open)(?door_closed)(?door_missing)...

Right now I have the 1220 cases in excel so making a source file CSV or other format is not difficult.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Your example is not clear. Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1619959/edit) and add a complete example with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great app called [TinyTask](https://sites.google.com/view/tinytask/)

It records a sequence of operations made by you, and then plays it back as many times as you wish

For your task, in your case, considering I have all the values in excel in the following format

```
| Column1  | Column2        |
| -------- | -------------- |
| DoorOpen | door_open      |
| ...      | ...            |
```

I would do the following:

1. Open notepad and Excel side by side, position the cursor in the **Column1** cell in Excel
2. Record one iteration of text replacement, for exammple

   2.1. Click on Excel upper panel to bring Excel to focus

   2.2. Press **Down**, **CTRL+C**

   2.3. Click on Notepad++ upper panel to bring Notepad++ to focus

   2.4. Press **CTRL+H**, **CTRL+V**

   2.5. Click on Excel upper panel to bring Excel to focus

   2.6. Press **Right**, **CTRL+C**, **DOWN**, **LEFT**

   2.7. Click on Notepad++ upper panel to bring Notepad++ to focus

   2.8. Press **Tab**, **CTRL+V**

   2.9. Press **Tab**, **Tab**, **Tab**, **Enter** (Replace all button), **ESC** (close replace window cause it will be opened again on next loop)
3. Playback the recorded macro as many times as there are rows in the Excel

*Just make sure that the end of operation brings to place where the next interation could start it's execution*

*Also you can use speed of 50x for example so the process goes fast*